# How can I create slope with precise angle in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, faces

I'm trying to create slope by rotating face with precise degrees and want the left and right walls stay vertical (I get it at angle like in picture). What is the best practice to to such things?

[image: Then rotate, wall is with angle]

Comment: You can use the keyboard. If you want to rotate 25 degrees on the X axis then you type"R X 25" If you need to rotate on all axis but Z then you type "R Shift Z 25"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I found a simple addon, called [Rotate Constraint Script](http://blendscript.blogspot.lt/2013/05/rotate-constraint-script.html). It does exactly what I need.

Select the face and press **Shift + Ctrl + R**.

After that it is possible to specify angle, axis and rotation point.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly the goal is to kind of rotate a face but without connected faces distorting:

[image: screenshot-understanding-correctly]

One way to do that is to use [*Shear*](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shear.html) tool; select the desired face, enter desired axis and amount of effect the face to be "rotated".

Note that as it works regarding current view, you should position viewport point of view accordingly, most likely in preset orthographic view. If shearing the top face of a cube by Y axis enter orthographic *Front* view and while shearing enter Y axis (not seen on gif here) and then amount of effect.

[image: GIF shearing]

Another much simpler way is not rotate enything but just grab edges by Z axis - one up, another down. It won't be rather simple to guess how much though as this will be moving edges, not rotating face.

Comment: Yes, I could just move Z axis, or sheer. But how can I make precise, for example 120 degrees angle between top and side face?

Comment: For now I found add on, which does exactly what I need:  [link]http://blendscript.blogspot.lt/2013/05/rotate-constraint-script.html